# paste does not work in a App called by the SMJobbless helper tool

Tags: cocoa, paste

I wrote an app "A" with a Helper Tool using SMJobbless. The helper tool call another app "B" located inside Resources folder of the app "A", via NSTask.
The problem is that everything seem works fine except the "paste" operation. This does not happen if app "B" is called from the command line (trying to reproduce the error).
Copy and Cut seem to work, although actually I'm not sure, why (for example) performing Cut over an NSTextField, the text disappears but I do not know if this is copied to the pasteboard ... maybe Paste does not work for this reason.
What change opening the app from the terminal or from an Helper Tool?
Sorry for my English, I hope someone can help me figure out where the problem is.

Comment: The app has the Edit menu obviously

Comment: Update: downloading ClipboardViewer from Apple her:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008825-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 now I can see that when I performing "cut" over some text, that is not copied to the general pasteboard. So no text to paste...

Comment: OMG, perhaps the root user (Helper Tool) does not share the same general pasteboard?